# How to use `<script setup>`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Vue version: `3.0.11`

With the following code:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="inc">{{ count }}</button>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  export const count = ref(0)

  export const inc = () => count.value++
</script>
```

I got:

```sh
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
 error  in ./src/views/HyperScript.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null


 @ ./src/views/HyperScript.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js 1:0-293 1:0-293 1:294-576 1:294-576
 @ ./src/views/HyperScript.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.6.175:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to add `export` in your script :

```
<template>
  <button @click="inc">{{ count }}</button>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const count = ref(0)

  const inc = () => count.value++
</script>
```

**[Live Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8YnV0dG9uIEBjbGljaz1cImluY1wiPnt7IGNvdW50IH19PC9idXR0b24+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0IHNldHVwPlxuICBpbXBvcnQgeyByZWYgfSBmcm9tICd2dWUnXG5cbiBjb25zdCBjb3VudCA9IHJlZigwKVxuXG4gY29uc3QgaW5jID0gKCkgPT4gY291bnQudmFsdWUrK1xuPC9zY3JpcHQ+In0=)**